# Xaviar does not process in real time? How do I improve it?

Tags: python, object-detection, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano, jetson-xavier

I am running YOLO v3 on Jetson Xavier, I am using python and OpenCV DNN module for inferencing, and it is pretty slow and seems as if it is not effective for my application. So I am looking for another detection model that can run in a real-time manner on Xaviar.
It has to have reasonable accuracy, so  I do not consider running YOLO-tiny. Any suggestion Please?
What model is capable of running real-time in a Xaviar device?

Comment: use haar cascades or dlib face detection is lighter than other models and works fine

Comment: but those are old, the accuracy might drop though.

Comment: every thing will depends how can you work whit produced data